# How to save a birthdate in Mongoose without throwing validation error

Tags: node.js, date, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my User model in Mongoose, I have a simple `dob` field with no format validation:

```
dob: {
    type: Date,
    alias: 'birthdate'
  },
```

Elsewhere in my code I am formatting three separate user-entered fields for day, month, and year. I am returning this as a new Date() but with a format of YYYY-MM-DD to avoid any weird timezone complications. The date is the date and time doesn't matter.

```
exports.formatDob = function (day, month, year) {
  let dob = new Date( parseInt(year), parseInt(month) - 1, parseInt(day), 0, 0, 0, 0 );
  return new Date(dob, '<YYYY-MM-DD>');
}
```

When I try to save this formatted date into Mongoose, I get the following error in my console:

> (node:32307) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User
>   validation failed: dob: Cast to Date failed for value "Invalid Date"
>   at path "dob"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) it's always recommended when it comes to working with dates.

However we can work around this just as easy as working with the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) obj api available methods for example if we want to return the format `YYYY-MM-DD` from a Date object we can just do the following:

```
let dob = new Date( parseInt(year), parseInt(month) - 1, parseInt(day));
return dob.getFullYear() + '-' + (dob.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dob.getDate();
```

```js
let dob = new Date();
console.log( dob.getFullYear() + '-' + (dob.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dob.getDate() );
```

Notice we have added `+ 1` to `getMonth` method because it returns a value for 0-11 and also we have added this expression inside parentheses so it is not evaluated as a string.